# Asp.net Web API RouteTemplate for passing multiple parameters to a method

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using the ASP.Net Web API and I need to pass in a different number of parameters to the accions in my controllers, but I haven't found (I'm new to Web API) a specific way to indicate a route template for the different methods I might have in my controllers.

Currently I have this template.

```
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I don't think I'll have to indicate a new template for each of the different methods I have in my controllers, do I?

As I told you, I'm really new to Web API and I haven't found much info about this , that's why I'd really apreciate if you could give me some advice or guidance.

### EDIT

It seems that the best way to go will be passing in the parameters in the query string like this:

```
api/controller/action?parm1=val1&par2=val2&par3=val3
```

the problem is that I have no idea how to put this in a route template or how to retrive these values from the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using The Route Attribute.

[Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)